# Manage/kill subprocess from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

This should be a basic problem, but I'm scratching my head on this one...

I'm trying to build the skeleton of a python script, part of which will use a loop to pipe strings into a camera SDK's console .exe (which opens, waits for user input, captures/saves an image with filename specified by input, waits for next input or to be killed).

I've built some test code which uses another simple .exe program that opens, takes user input, writes it to a .txt, and waits for next input or to be killed:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen("testinput1.exe", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False)
bytes = str.encode("no")
for n in range(1, 5):
    p.stdin.write(bytes)
p.stdin.close()
p.terminate()
```

However, this code on its own doesn't successfully open the process, write to it, and close - mysteriously, it doesn't do anything at all.

If I remove the line

```
p.terminate()
```

I can successfully pipe my "nonononono" into the text file, but the subprocess isn't closed, and the .txt file grows by 1KB/sec until I close the "testinput1.exe"

Do I need to put some kind of wait before p.terminate()? Or am I going about the whole process incorrectly?

Comment: The code does open the process, write to it and terminate it. It just terminates the process before the process can do anything with the sent data.

Comment: unrelated: don't use `PIPE` for stdout/stderr unless you read from the pipes, otherwise the child process may hang.

Comment: How do you know that the child process has finished processing the previous input and waits for the new one?